# how can i chain these functions so that when once completes, the next fires?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a div that I clear the contents of, but then want to put something new in it's place, how can I string these functions so that one only fires after the previous one completes

```
$('#nner_container').fadeOut(300, function(){

    $('#header_div').after('<div id="inner_container" style="dispay:none"></div>');
       //when this insertion of inner_container completes, fill it with some content
       //and when that completes, fadeIn inner_container

});
```

most jquery functions seem to take additional functions as a final parameter, which I thought was used for exactly this purpose. But not so with `after()`. Or am I doing something incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: `after` is not asynchronous, so a callback is unnecessary.

Comment: @Shmiddty Thanks. Can you explain what you mean by it not being 'asynchronous'?

Comment: He means it's synchronous, no other actions will be taken before it's done, so all you have to do is put whatever you want on the next line or chain it after the insertion, and the element will be present in the DOM.

Comment: What's the problem here? There's no callback, because adding stuff to the DOM is instantaneous and blocking (the script only continues to process once the element has been added). Just fade it in after.

Comment: An async function basically calls data from the server. It promises to return data, to some function, at a later time. Therefore, your callback will not necessarily be executed immediately after you make the async call. I recommend reading the ajax page of jquery's docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It is performed immediately. There is no delay, so the javascript thread is "locked" until it completes. This means, basically, that the next line of code will not start until that line is complete. The animations have callbacks because they perform multiple actions over a set duration using timeouts; the callback is invoked once all of these actions have been completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you add the new div, just fade in the `inner_container`:

```
$('#inner_container').fadeOut(300, function(){

    $('#header_div').after('<div id="inner_container" style="dispay:none"></div>');
    $('#inner_container').fadeIn(300);
});
```

The `after` function is synchronous, meaning that the next statement will not execute until the previous statement has completed.

On the other hand, `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` execute asynchronously, meaning that the next statement may execute before the effect has completed. This is why the `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` functions need callbacks to execute when the effect has completed.

Comment: You're missing the i in `#inner_container` for both selectors

Comment: @AdamMerrifield: So is the OP. If that's how his code is written, who am I to change it? :-) I kid...I fixed it. I actually did notice that before, but for some reason I didn't want to change it.

Answer (score 1):

try .replaceWith() function if you're replacing content

Answer (score 0):

Since `.after` completes immediately and therefore doesn't need (or have) a callback, you can just chain it by just putting what you want to do next on the next line;

```
$('#inner_container').fadeOut(300, function(){    
    $('#header_div').after('<div id="inner_container" style="dispay:none"></div>');
    $('#inner_container').fadeIn(300);
});
```

Asynchronous methods are usually methods that can take a while, like in this case `FadeIn` and `FadeOut` that need a set time to complete. Most if not all DOM manipulating functions that aren't animations are actually synchronous and can be coded as classic code without callbacks.